# insert date from jsp into database

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Below code is only a part of the application.First page is Login page when submited, it will go to `TimseSheet.jsp` page. In Timsesheet.jsp page we need to fill the id and date and save the values to database but it is storing `null` values in the database table.

Please tell me how to insert date in the table.

In Jsp page:TimseSheet.jsp

```
 <form action="TimseSheetProcess.jsp" method="post">
 <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>  
 <td><input type="date" name="logindate" required="required" /></td>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

In EmployeeBean class:

```
public class EmployeeBean {
private String empid;
private Date logindate;
 public String getEmp_id() {
    return empid;
}

public void setEmp_id(String empid) {
    this.empid = empid;
}
public Date getLoginDate() {
    return logindate;
}

public void setLoginDate(Date logindate) {
    this.logindate = logindate;
}
```

}
In TimseSheetDao class:

```
public class TimseSheetDao {
public static int insert(EmployeeBean eb){
int status=0;  
PreparedStatement ps = null;  

ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into tab values(?,?");  
ps.setString(1,eb.getEmp_id());   
ps.setDate(2,eb.getLoginDate()); 
status=ps.executeUpdate(); 
   }
}
```

In TimseSheetProcess.jsp:

```
<%@page import="com.eis.Dao.TimseSheetDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" scope="session" class="com.eis.bean.EmployeeBean"/>  

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  
<%  out.print("You are in loop"); 
int status=TimseSheetDao.insert(obj);
if(status>0) { 
out.print("You are successfully registered");  
response.sendRedirect("timsesheet.jsp");
}
else{
out.print("Error");
}
%>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the code where you are calling dao?

Comment: show the TimseSheetProcess.jsp file

Comment: @sooraoadman from the Process jsp

Comment: @SpringLearner Please check the code i have edited the heading name.

Comment: it seems  EmployeeBean null  check whether you are getting or not

Comment: From where you setting the value to EmployeeBean ?\

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the id and the date at the same parameterindex "1" of the preparement statement!  That's wrong ....

```
ps.setString(1,eb.getEmp_id());   
ps.setDate(1,eb.getLoginDate());
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. By mistake I did that. But it is still showing the same null as value in the database

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Is the property filled in the bean? Is the date in the bean of type java.util.Date?

Comment: No It is of java.sql.Date type

Comment: I think it must be of type java.util.Date in the bean, and you have to create a new java.sql.Date(...) if you are set parameter of the preparement statement

Comment: I did that. But It is still the same,  showing null as value

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is the property in the bean filled?

Comment: Yes, I debugged! same thing its not showing anything there as well